# Easy way to make many files with names from the list

Tags: notepad++, filenames

I have a text file with 30 names in it. I need to make 30 empty text files each called name from the list.
Is there an easy way of doing this? Naming 30 text files one by one seems kind of frustrating.
I use notepad++

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're on Windows, if the filenames are in `filenames.txt`, one per line, do

```
for /f "delims=" %F in (filenames.txt) do copy nul "%F"
```

If you have multiple words per line, this will create files whose names contain spaces.

Comment: I have 1 name per line. I type this in cmd? And what will it give out?

Comment: Ok I tried it and it gave me many files but not text files. Also one file was "blabla" type of file because name contained a dot "name.blabla".

Comment: It should give you empty files (that's what `copy nul ...` does). If your filename list contains `foo.txt` and `bar.txt`, then you should get (empty) text files. If your filename list contains `red.jpg` and `blue.jpg`, then you should get (empty/invalid) JPEG files. And if you have non-alphanumeric characters like `^` in your filename list, then you will get files with non-alphanumeric characters in their names.

Comment: Ok so how do I make textfiles instead of empty files?

Comment: Didn't I answer that when I said "if your filename list contains `foo.txt` and `bar.txt`, then you should get (empty) text files"? But, if your filename list contains filenames without extensions, change the end of the command in my answer to `do copy nul "%F".txt`.

Comment: Oh I meant empty text files. My bad. Sorry. Anyway thanks :) The file contains list of names not filenames.

Comment: I tried to put your code in `createfiles.bat` and placed it in a "my-scripts" directory (which is added to system's PATH variable). In which ever directory I am working, I want to create a `filenames.txt` and just execute it. But its not working, Can you help me why? and how to make it work?

Comment: @claws: Ah, if you’re putting the command into a `.bat` file, you have to double the `%` characters: `for /f "delims=" %%F in (filenames.txt) do copy nul "%%F"`. If that doesn’t fix it, explain what happens. “its not working” gives me no information, so I can’t help you.  P.S. I’m not logging in to this site every day, so I might not see your response immediately.